# C++ dll errors (__vcrt_cleanup_type_info_names)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

the following DLLs in my project ;

- vcruntime140d.dll
- msvcr110d
- msvcr110.dll
- msvcp140d.dll
- msvcp110d.dll
- msvcp110.dll

but I get the following error..

[image]

Comment: Why do you have both debug and non-debug libraries, and libraries from both VC 2012 and VC 2015 in your project? These libraries are definitely not compatible within a single project.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess:  Your DLL was built using a pre-release version of Visual Studio 2015 and it needs to be rebuilt with the release version (RTM or later).  Binary compatibility is not guaranteed for previews before the Release Candidate.

`__vcrt_cleanup_type_info_names` was replaced by `__std_type_info_destroy_list`.